# Open file without warnings prompt

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My application is developed in C++ & I used MSVC to compile it. My question is; whenever I attempt to open the application, I get an "open file warning" asking if I would like to run or cancel this application. Is it possible to evade this warning, or get around it by triggering some sort of #pragma or possibly, a linker to my compiler to not have this warning come up on execution, and instead just execute the program?

[Warning Message http://opensource.geneanet.org/attachments/72/en-open-file-security-warning-2.jpg](http://opensource.geneanet.org/attachments/72/en-open-file-security-warning-2.jpg)

^ How can I get around it? How can my program open without having this appear? Is there any way to get around it? Thanks.

Comment: Hmmmm, sounds like the warning VS give you when you´re attemping to run a program that is already compiled, but the code has changed and also the new code have some error/s. Try to clean or rebuild from the popup menu from the project.

Comment: No no, what I'm saying is. When I execute the program I get a pop-up before the execution asking me if I want to run or cancel the application. Like a warning before the application is executed after I open it.

Comment: Screenshot it and put it in your post.

Comment: is it something related to UAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This warning is put in place explicitly to tell users that a program was downloaded from the network (the so-called "mark of the web"), and by design is not removable by application developers.

You can supply a publisher name and similar data to the user if you sign your application with an [authenticode certificate](http://www.symantec.com/code-signing/microsoft-authenticode). I believe that you'll still get a warning message but it won't say "The publisher could not be verified." and won't have the red X shield logo.

Comment: :S You can remove the warning.. Just uncheck the "always ask for this type of file".. OR go into http://i.imgur.com/22mCXhK.png  and change it.. Maybe even add an exception to the firewall or smartscreen.

Comment: @Brandon: On that specific downloaded instance of the file, you can uncheck that box. In the general case for all users who download your file? No. The image you linked to has nothing to do with this; the mark of the web is not related to nor is affected by UAC settings.

Comment: @Brandon: (Reply to your edited comment) This isn't related to firewall or smart screen settings either.

Comment: By signing my application with a certificate, this warning will not  appear?

Comment: @user: I believe you'll get a different, less dangerous looking, warning. I have been unable to verify this though. YMMV

Comment: I signed my application but I got this "This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store." in the description. What is meant by this?

Comment: @user: It means that the target machine does not trust the certificate. You need a certificate from a trusted root authority, who will verify your identity and issue you a certificate. The root authority is responsible for looking at the thing you sign and verifying that you are in fact the signer. All the target machine has now is "user325 says that he is user325", while getting a certificate from an actual CA will be "VeriSign says that he is user325".

Comment: Well I have a certificate from a CA, I think a better question would be: How exactly do I sign my application with the certificate? Is there a guide out there with a step-by-step routine I can follow? Thanks! Does visual studio provide some sort of 'wizard' for this?

Comment: @user: I don't believe so. I rigged up an AfterBuild task for this: https://github.com/BillyONeal/Instalog/blob/a167667501598dd8ce2f1ca5c396f6e833e25a27/Instalog/Instalog.vcxproj#L81